# Looking for a chemical to calibrate a temperature sensor

Tags: physical-chemistry, materials

The best method for calibration would be a bath filled with a chemical at its melting point with a solid/liquid composition. 
The constraints being that it must be hydrophobic and relatively non-corrosive and non-toxic with a melting point between (say) 20 °C and 60 °C. Needless to say, but I’ll say it anyway, the chemical must have a very precise melting point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The standard point recommended in that range by the CIPM's ITS-90 calibration standard is the melting point of gallium at 29.7646 °C. Gallium is not known to be particularly toxic, but it can embrittle metals so is ideally used/stored in glass or plastic containers. It's used as a standard because it is relatively easy to make very pure and is stable in storage. Also, by picking an ITS-90 standard, you can ensure your thermometer is calibrated to the same standard as many other high precision thermometers. N.B. ITS-90 specifies specifically the *melting* point of gallium, not the freezing point, unlike some of the other calibration standards.

Answer (score 3):

In the old days, you'd look it up in the CRC organic chemical tables, but now you can go to a site such as http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/cmp/cmp.html and enter the desired m.p. and constituents. Here is the result for a search for 50C (+-5C) m.p. without O, N and S so they're likely hydrophobic.

P-DICHLOROBENZENE
PENTAMETHYLBENZENE
1-METHYL-4-PHENYLBENZENE
1,2,3-TRICHLOROBENZENE
1-ETHYL-4-PHENYLBENZENE
1,2-DIPHENYLETHANE
1,1-DIPHENYL-1-PROPENE
CYCLOTETRADECANE
2-BROMONAPHTHALENE
1,2,3,4-TETRACHLOROBENZENE
1,2,3,5-TETRACHLOROBENZENE
P-CHLOROIODOBENZENE

Taking P-DICHLOROBENZENE as an example, you would find it melts at 53.5 C and is mildly toxic, but is used in mothballs, so is a regularly available consumer item not requiring HM permitting to buy. See http://www.epa.gov/airtoxics/hlthef/dich-ben.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,4-Dichlorobenzene for more information.

Comment: I like both answers so far and have had some fun looking up possible compounds to use in the colby DB.  **Menthol** seems to qualify and would probably smell better than dichlorobenzene, although it is slightly less hydrophobic.  p-cresol and 1-methylcyclopentanol also seem like pretty good candidates if you can get a hold of them.